# proj.xll add-in wont load after added to excel

Tags: excel, dll, add-in, xll, proj

I have searched and searched to find a solution to a .xll excel add-in not working correctly.

The add-in is proj.xll (https://github.com/jbuonagurio/proj.xll)

The instructions simply say to;

Copy proj.xll to %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\AddIns.

Go to Excel Options, Add-ins, Manage Excel Add-ins. Click Browse, and select proj.xll.

After doing that I load my spreadsheet and get this error;

> The file format and extension of 'proj.xll' don't match. The file could be        corrupted or unsafe. Unless you trust its soruce, don't open it. Do you want to open it anyway?

I click yes and I get cells with "*LËÝbÉÜRichcÉÜPEL*" etc gibberish text in them.

Some websites indicate that a .dll file is missing which is needed by the add-in, but I am unsure what dll file that is, how to find out what dll file I need and where to put the dll file if I do find it.

I have tried to get this add-in to work on multiple computers and different versions of excel installed.

If anyone could offer assistance that would be fantastic.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use dependency walker ([here](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)) to inspect the generated xll and to look for missing dependencies. Also be sure that the xll is in the same architecture (64 vs 32 bits) than excel.

See also : ["addin.XLL is in a different format" issue, cannot open the xll I created by myself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760755/addin-xll-is-in-a-different-format-issue-cannot-open-the-xll-i-created-by-mys?rq=1)
 .